# How do I reign in the Amazon SDK's logging? (using SLF4J & Logback)

Tags: amazon-web-services, clojure, slf4j, logback, c3p0

How can I have my application code log at the `DEBUG` level, but restrain certain library dependencies to the `WARN` level? Specifically, I'm having a hard time controlling [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) and the [Amazon SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/). Can anyone tell me why my setup isn't working? Because I don't understand why I'm still seeing AWS's incredibly verbose DEBUG logging still in the log files.

Below I've included my `logback.xml` and relevant excerpts of my `project.clj`.

```xml
<configuration>

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- daily rollover -->
      <fileNamePattern>
        ${catalina.home}/logs/MY_APP.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
      </fileNamePattern>
      <!-- the "%i" is because of the SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP -->

      <!-- keep 5 days' worth of history -->
      <maxHistory>5</maxHistory>

      <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
        <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 20MB -->
        <maxFileSize>20MB</maxFileSize>
      </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>

  </appender>

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>

  <!-- The amazon sdk -->
  <logger name="com.amazonaws" level="WARN" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </logger>

  <!-- The c3p0 connection pooling library that Korma uses. -->
  <logger name="com.mchange" level="WARN" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </logger>

</configuration>
```

```lisp
(defproject …
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
                 [org.slf4j/slf4j-api "1.7.2"]

                 ;; Amazon Web Services' S3
                 [clj-aws-s3 "0.3.2"]
                 [org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j "1.7.2"] ; for underlying AWS SDK

                 ;; SQL abstraction
                 [korma "0.3.0-beta11"]
                 [org.slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j "1.7.2"] ; for c3p0 (package begins with "com.mchange"), which is a dependency of Korma

                 ;; HTTP abstraction
                 [ring/ring-core "1.1.6"]

                 ;; routing DSL
                 [compojure "1.1.3"]

                 ;; for determining MIME types of sent files
                 [com.novemberain/pantomime "1.4.0"]

                 ;; Take a wild guess.
                 [org.clojure/tools.logging "0.2.4"]

                 ;; Finally, the actual logging implementation
                 [ch.qos.logback/logback-classic "1.0.7"]

                 ;; Environmental variables that integrate with profiles
                 [environ "0.3.0"]]

  :exclusions [commons-logging
               log4j]
…
```

Comment: Did you try setting `debug="true"` on the root `configuration` element?

Comment: re c3p0, you might try overriding korma's version choice and using c3p0-0.9.5-pre4. c3p0 0.9.5.x supports logging directly to the slf4j api without use of the log4j bridge, and configuration might be more straightforward that way. It'll probably happen automatically if you remove the log4j api, but to be sure you log to slf4j, add to c3p0.properties or as a System property 'com.mchange.v2.log.MLog= slf4j' See http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0-0.9.5-pre4/#configuring_logging

Comment: @Alex: yep, I have tried that, and I don't _recall_ it telling me anything useful. That said, I'll certainly try it again.

Comment: @SteveWaldman Thank you for that *excellent* tip! I'll give a different version of c3p0 a shot.